# Maximizing a variable sum

Tags: calculus, optimization

I am analysing the worst case scenenario for an algorithm. It reduces to show that the following function is maximun when $a_1 =c , a_i=0, i\geq 2$

$$
\max \sum_{i=1}^n (n+1-i)\times a_i 
$$
subject to $\sum_{i=1}^na_i=c$ , $a_i$ is a continues variable

It seems pretty obvious but I lack of the mathematical tools for a proper proof.

Comment: I think you also require $a_i \ge 0$. Consider the case when some $a_i$ is nonzero, $i > 1$, and the possibility of improving on the sum by transferring that amount to $a_1$.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, if $w_1=\max_i w_i$, the maximum of $\sum_{i=1}^n w_i a_i$ subject to $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i=c$ (and $a_i\ge 0$ for all $i$, as hardmath added) is attained when $a_1=c$ and $a_i=0$ for $i\ge 2$. Proof: 
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n w_i a_i \right) - w_1 c = \sum_{i=1}^n (w_i-w_1)a_i\le 0 $$
with equality iff $a_i=0$ whenever $w_i=w_1$.